# How to change a shape's height based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, height, shapes

I'm trying to make my shape change height automatically, based on what is in a cell, when that cell value is changed.

The tricky part is that it would be 1" of height per every 1000 inputted into that cell.

I thought it would be something like the below, but that's based on ranges and doesn't take the ratio into consideration and is pretty tedious.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_ShapeHeight()
    
If Range("C8").Value >= 1000 And Range("").Value <= 2000 Then
        
    Shapes("Rectangle 1").Height = 1
    
Else
    
    If Range("C8").Value >= 2000 And Range("").Value <= 3000 Then
        
        Shapes("Rectangle 1").Height = 2

        '---And so on..

End Sub
```

Screenshot of Sheet1
[image]

Comment: Side note: you're including `2000` in both cases. I think you want `< 2000` in the first case, not `<=`. Similarly for `3000`.

Comment: I think: `Shapes("Rectangle 1").Height = Int(Range("C8").Value/1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the following. Note that the unit for [`Shape.Height`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.height) is points, not inches.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C8")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim calcHeight As Single
    calcHeight = Int(Me.Range("C8").Value / 1000) * 72 ' 72 points per inch
    
    Me.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Height = calcHeight
End Sub
```